# What is the runtime type of the HttpRequest.InputStream property in an ASP.NEt application

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, abstract-class

According to MSDN documentation, the HttpRequest.InputStream property is a `Stream` type, but `Stream` is an abstract type. What are the possible runtime types of the HttpRequest.InputStream property, and under what conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpRequest.cs,28daaa1aa21c327d) it is `HttpInputStream`.

Comment: Didn't know about that reference source portal. Very useful.

Comment: @DanielArant This is a great portal for inspecting Full .NET Framework. The core part of this sources where published on github.com/dotnet and github.com/aspnet repositories

Comment: This actually helps with another problem that I've had: trying to step into framework code during a debug session.